# Why is my EMA value on pine off from the built in version on TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'm trying to use an EMA and VWAP from the 1 hour chart on a 5 minute chart to get the greater trend on SPY for backtesting. But the values that are shown are different from the built-in version in TradingView.

```
emaout = ema(close, 200)
vwapout = vwap(hlc3)
ema = security("SPY", "60", emaout, gaps=true)
plot(ema, color=color.red)
vwap1 = security("SPY", "60", vwapout, gaps=true)
plot(vwap1, color=color.blue)
```

If I just do `plot(vwapout, color=color.blue)` or `plot(emaout, color=color.red)` and switch to the 1 hour timeframe it is the same as the built in indicator, so I'm thinking it's an issue with `security()`. I also tried a suggestion I saw to let `security()` calculate the line so I tried this:

```
ema = security("SPY", "60", ema(emaout, 200), gaps=true)
vwap1 = security("SPY", "60", vwap(vwapout), gaps=true)
```

However the values are still incorrect. I am checking them with the TradingView indicators set to the 1 hour timeframe. Any assistance is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it does [not repaint](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html?highlight=repaint#avoiding-repainting)

Try this:

```
ema = request.security('SPY', '60', ta.ema(close, 200)[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me. Were you able to get the values the same? Mine are still off.

Comment: my mistake. 
edit my answer

Comment: I think this is a problem with the security function itself, because that doesn't work either. Thank you for trying to help though.